# Docusign - Salesforce : real-time document status updates // know how signers interact with the enveloppe

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-lightning, docusign-sdk, docusignapextoolkit

I am wondering if it is possible in Salesforce to track how my signers are interacting with my Docusign contract.
For example, I want to know how much time my signer spent on page 1, page 2, etc.

Is it possible to do such things ? I know some Esign actors provide it but Docusign seems to be more robust with thousands of documents.

Thanks a mil,

I was expecting to have natively this capability thanks to Docusign on AppExchange.

Answer (score 2):

My name is Conar and I'm with Docusign Developer Support.

We have discussed this with our team and the feedback is that no, this type of tracking capabilities are not available for Salesforce out of the box.

Please confirm if you are happy for us to close this case.

Best regards,
Conar | DocuSign Developer Support